# Как применить оптимизацию к изображению в tensorflow, чтобы вывод нейросети был высоким?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch

Есть нейросеть на `keras`, у нее есть 1 вывод `softmax` (стандартная модель собака или кошка)
хочу применить оптимизацию на изображение кошки так, чтобы модель думала что это собака
на `pytorch` такое легко сделать, а как это сделать на `tensorflow`?

на `pytorch` выглядит это так:

```
import torch
from torchvision import transforms
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("cat.jpg").resize((100,100))

to_tensor = transforms.ToTensor()

img = to_tensor(img)

img.requires_grad = True
print(img.shape)

nn = torch.load("catvdog.pth") #replace to real model

y = torch.tensor([1.0])
optim = torch.optim.Adam([img])
loss = torch.nn.MSELoss()
#tensorflow analog?
for i in range(100):
  losses = loss(nn(img),y)
  losses.backward()
  optim.step()
  optim.zero_grad()
  print(losses.data)
  ...
```

ссылка на [файлы](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZqcFjVPLEqTqf2fnRBKyGM4rH_uorW0f/view?usp=sharing)
ссылка на [collab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1oMwbyPtRUIVL1Kd3yhMmBOnOURH6hVuF?usp=sharing)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: исправлять вроде мне нечего

Comment: А не адекватный ответ - вам нужно изучить  tensorflow. Без деталей, таких как исходный код, ваш вариант кода, невозможно дать хоть какую-то конкретную информацию. Ясновидение и предсказание грядущего на кофейной гуще тут не работает... :-)

Comment: добавил примерный код на pytorch

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в код комментарии в места ответственные за ваш вопрос... и будем надеяться, что специалисты по  tensorflow смогут провести аналогии и предложить свои варианты. )

Comment: вот есть collab
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1oMwbyPtRUIVL1Kd3yhMmBOnOURH6hVuF?usp=sharing